# How to normalize Recharts ComposedChart with one dataKey significantly greater than other

Tags: recharts

I'm wondering if it's possible to "normalize" dataset value for multiple rechart instances (let's say Area and Bar).

The problem is that my dataset is a monthly Stats chart for orders income and amount. And one value is significantly greater than the other.

Example data looks:

```js
{
  income: 5050,
  amount: 3,
},
{
  income: 8600,
  amount: 5,
},
```

Component (simplified)

```
            <ComposedChart data={daysData}>
              <Area dataKey="income" />
              <Bar dataKey="amount"  />
            </ComposedChart>
```

This results in Bar chart barely visible on charts.
I would like bars to be for example half of the container height despite the original value is low.

I could manually multiple `amount` by 1000 and somehow transform tooltip values, but this is not a stable solution, because amounts could be measured in hundreds of thousands or even millions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I wrote simple normalizing functions. It works but doesn't seem right.

Is it anything similar in functionality I could do with native recharts params?

```js
  const daysDataNormalized = useMemo(() => {
    const greatestIncome = daysData.reduce((acc, x) => (acc.income > x.income ? acc : x)).income;
    const greatestAmount = daysData.reduce((acc, x) => (acc.amount > x.amount ? acc : x)).amount;

    const multiplier = greatestIncome / greatestAmount / 2;

    return daysData.map((stat) => ({
      name: stat.name,
      income: stat.income,
      amount: stat.amount * multiplier,
      amountTooltip: stat.amount,
    }));
  }, [daysData]);

  const TooltipFormater = (value, name, props) => {
    if (name === 'amount') {
      return value;
    }
    if (name === 'income') {
      return props.payload.amountTooltip;
    }
  };
```